# Get current location in offline mode using cell tower with less battery and high accuracy

Tags: java, android, gps, currentlocation, location-client

I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) links to get current location. Here without using Wi-fi and GPS getting current location but it is not updating when location changed, if I on GPS/Wi-fi it starting updating. Here I want to get updates with based on only cell tower with low battery consumption and high accuracy.

This is my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.offline;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        LocationListener,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;

    // Handles to UI widgets
    private TextView mLatLng;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private ProgressBar mActivityIndicator;
    private TextView mConnectionState;
    private TextView mConnectionStatus;

    // Handle to SharedPreferences for this app
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    // Handle to a SharedPreferences editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get handles to the UI view objects
        mLatLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_lng);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
//        mActivityIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.address_progress);
        mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_connection_state);
        mConnectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_connection_status);

        // Create a new global location parameters object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

        // Open Shared Preferences
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Get an editor
        mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        // If the client is connected
        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            stopPeriodicUpdates();
        }

        // After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
        mLocationClient.disconnect();

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        // Save the current setting for updates
        mEditor.putBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, mUpdatesRequested);
        mEditor.commit();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        /*
         * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here;
         * instead, wait for onResume()
         */
        mLocationClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // If the app already has a setting for getting location updates, get it
        if (mPrefs.contains(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED)) {
            mUpdatesRequested = mPrefs.getBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);

        // Otherwise, turn off location updates until requested
        } else {
            mEditor.putBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);
            mEditor.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        // Choose what to do based on the request code
        switch (requestCode) {

            // If the request code matches the code sent in onConnectionFailed
            case LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :

                switch (resultCode) {
                    // If Google Play services resolved the problem
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        // Log the result
                        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.resolved));

                        // Display the result
                        mConnectionState.setText(R.string.connected);
                        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.resolved);
                    break;

                    // If any other result was returned by Google Play services
                    default:
                        // Log the result
                        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.no_resolution));

                        // Display the result
                        mConnectionState.setText(R.string.disconnected);
                        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.no_resolution);

                    break;
                }

            // If any other request code was received
            default:
               // Report that this Activity received an unknown requestCode
               Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                       getString(R.string.unknown_activity_request_code, requestCode));

               break;
        }
    }


    private boolean servicesConnected() {

        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.play_services_available));

            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Display an error dialog
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
            if (dialog != null) {
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void getLocation(View v) {

        // If Google Play Services is available
        if (servicesConnected()) {

            // Get the current location
            Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

            // Display the current location in the UI
            mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, currentLocation));
        }
    }

    // For Eclipse with ADT, suppress warnings about Geocoder.isPresent()
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void getAddress(View v) {

        // In Gingerbread and later, use Geocoder.isPresent() to see if a geocoder is available.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD && !Geocoder.isPresent()) {
            // No geocoder is present. Issue an error message
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_geocoder_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (servicesConnected()) {

            // Get the current location
            Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

            // Turn the indefinite activity indicator on
            mActivityIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Start the background task
            (new MainActivity.GetAddressTask(this)).execute(currentLocation);
        }
    }

    public void startUpdates(View v) {
        mUpdatesRequested = true;

        if (servicesConnected()) {
            startPeriodicUpdates();
        }
    }

    public void stopUpdates(View v) {
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

        if (servicesConnected()) {
            stopPeriodicUpdates();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.connected);

        if (mUpdatesRequested) {
            startPeriodicUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.disconnected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {

                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);



            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            // If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the user with the error.
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.location_updated);

        // In the UI, set the latitude and longitude to the value received
        mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, location));
    }

    private void startPeriodicUpdates() {

        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        mConnectionState.setText(R.string.location_requested);
    }

    private void stopPeriodicUpdates() {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        mConnectionState.setText(R.string.location_updates_stopped);
    }


    protected class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, String> {

        // Store the context passed to the AsyncTask when the system instantiates it.
        Context localContext;

        // Constructor called by the system to instantiate the task
        public GetAddressTask(Context context) {

            // Required by the semantics of AsyncTask
            super();

            // Set a Context for the background task
            localContext = context;
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(localContext, Locale.getDefault());

            // Get the current location from the input parameter list
            Location location = params[0];

            // Create a list to contain the result address
            List <Address> addresses = null;

            // Try to get an address for the current location. Catch IO or network problems.
            try {

                 addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(), 1
                );

                // Catch network or other I/O problems.
                } catch (IOException exception1) {

                    // Log an error and return an error message
                    Log.e(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.IO_Exception_getFromLocation));

                    // print the stack trace
                    exception1.printStackTrace();

                    // Return an error message
                    return (getString(R.string.IO_Exception_getFromLocation));

                // Catch incorrect latitude or longitude values
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception2) {

                    // Construct a message containing the invalid arguments
                    String errorString = getString(
                            R.string.illegal_argument_exception,
                            location.getLatitude(),
                            location.getLongitude()
                    );
                    // Log the error and print the stack trace
                    Log.e(LocationUtils.APPTAG, errorString);
                    exception2.printStackTrace();

                    //
                    return errorString;
                }
                // If the reverse geocode returned an address
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

                    // Get the first address
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);

                    // Format the first line of address
                    String addressText = getString(R.string.address_output_string,

                            // If there's a street address, add it
                            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
                                    address.getAddressLine(0) : "",

                            // Locality is usually a city
                            address.getLocality(),

                            // The country of the address
                            address.getCountryName()
                    );

                    // Return the text
                    return addressText;

                // If there aren't any addresses, post a message
                } else {
                  return getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String address) {

            // Turn off the progress bar
            mActivityIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Set the address in the UI
            mAddress.setText(address);
        }
    }

   private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {

        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
            errorCode,
            this,
            LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {

            // Create a new DialogFragment in which to show the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();

            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);

            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
        }
    }

    ublic static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;

        /**
         * Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
         */
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

       public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        /*
         * This method must return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
         */
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }
}
```

LocationUtils.java

```
package com.example.offline;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;


/**
 * Defines app-wide constants and utilities
 */
public final class LocationUtils {

    // Debugging tag for the application
    public static final String APPTAG = "LocationSample";

    // Name of shared preferences repository that stores persistent state
    public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES =
            "com.example.android.location.SHARED_PREFERENCES";

    // Key for storing the "updates requested" flag in shared preferences
    public static final String KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED =
            "com.example.android.location.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED";

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    public final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    /*
     * Constants for location update parameters
     */
    // Milliseconds per second
    public static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

    // The update interval
    public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;

    // A fast interval ceiling
    public static final int FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS = 1;

    // Update interval in milliseconds
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

    // A fast ceiling of update intervals, used when the app is visible
    public static final long FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS;

    // Create an empty string for initializing strings
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = new String();

    /**
     * Get the latitude and longitude from the Location object returned by
     * Location Services.
     *
     * @param currentLocation A Location object containing the current location
     * @return The latitude and longitude of the current location, or null if no
     * location is available.
     */
    public static String getLatLng(Context context, Location currentLocation) {
        // If the location is valid
        if (currentLocation != null) {

            // Return the latitude and longitude as strings
            return context.getString(
                    R.string.latitude_longitude,
                    currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                    currentLocation.getLongitude());
        } else {

            // Otherwise, return the empty string
            return EMPTY_STRING;
        }
    }
}
```

LocationServiceErrorMessages.java

```
package com.example.offline;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;


/**
 * Map error codes to error messages.
 */
public class LocationServiceErrorMessages {

    // Don't allow instantiation
    private LocationServiceErrorMessages() {}

    public static String getErrorString(Context context, int errorCode) {

        // Get a handle to resources, to allow the method to retrieve messages.
        Resources mResources = context.getResources();

        // Define a string to contain the error message
        String errorString;

        // Decide which error message to get, based on the error code.
        switch (errorCode) {
            case ConnectionResult.DEVELOPER_ERROR:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_misconfigured);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.INTERNAL_ERROR:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_internal);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.INVALID_ACCOUNT:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_invalid_account);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_license_check_failed);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.NETWORK_ERROR:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_network);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_needs_resolution);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_disabled);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_invalid);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_missing);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_outdated);
                break;

            case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
                errorString = mResources.getString(
                        R.string.connection_error_sign_in_required);
                break;

            default:
                errorString = mResources.getString(R.string.connection_error_unknown);
                break;
        }

        // Return the error message
        return errorString;
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as I know you can't get the location using the cell towers if you are online. The only thing you will be able to do is get the ID of the cell tower the device is connected to. You might have a DB with the location of all the cell tower locations, but that seems like a huge thing, almost impossible with the "normal" resources. If you want high accuracy and low consumption, wifi is the way to go. With cell towers you will need to be online and the accuracy will be quite low. Either way, the best thing to do I think it will be to use the fused location service

Comment: I am getting location based on Mobile net work but not updating in background